# C++: Pointer contains different address after being passed

Tags: c++, pointers, visual-studio-2013, multiple-inheritance, memory-address

So i have some code like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base1 {};
class Base2 {};

class A
{
public:
    A() {}
    void foo(Base2* ptr) { cout << "This is A. B is at the address " << ptr << endl; }
};

A *global_a;

class B : public Base1, public Base2
{
public:
    B() {}
    void bar()
    {
        cout << "This is B. I am at the address " << this << endl;
        global_a->foo(this);
    }
};

int main()
{
    global_a = new A();
    B *b = new B();

    b->bar();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

But this is the output i get after compiling with Visual Studio 2013:

> This is B. I am at the address 0045F0B8
>
> This is A. B is at the address 0045F0B9
>
> Press any key to continue . . .

Can somebody please explain why the addresses are different?

Comment: Can somebody please explain why this got voted down? I think it is a reasonable question considering it is not immediately obvious why this happens, and i believe that many people could benefit from reading the answers posted here.

Comment: I can provide a partial explanation: This question is indeed reasonable, and even moreover, rather interesting. Some of the users on SO, however, aren't (if you may ascribe such characteristics to human beings). There are plenty of annoying nit pickers here thinking they're really hot-shot programming genius. Try not to take them too seriously, the majority of SO community consists of users with a positive approach, who are willing to help. You get my +1, as do the two answers below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`0x0045F0B8` is the address of the complete `B` object. `0x0045F0B9` is the address of the `Base2` subobject of the `B` object.

In general the address of the complete object might not be the same as the address of a base class subobject. In your case the `B` object is probably laid out as follows:

```
+---+-------+
|   | Base1 | <-- 0x0045F0B8
| B |-------+
|   | Base2 | <-- 0x0045F0B9
+---+-------+
```

Each base class occupies one byte and `Base1` is laid out before `Base2`. The pointer to the complete `B` points to the beginning, which is at `0x0045F0B8`, but the pointer to the `Base2` points to the address inside the complete `B` object at which the `Base2` subobject starts, which is `0x0045F0B9`.

However when I compile your program on my system using g++ 4.8, I get the same address printed in both lines. This is presumably because the implementation is allowed to allocate *no space at all* for empty base classes (the so-called **empty base class optimization**) and the two base class subobjects `Base1` and `Base2` are both located at the very beginning of the `B` object, taking no space, and sharing their address with `B`.

Comment: Is there any way i can ask an instance of B for its full address? I would like to have a function in A that compares the addresses of two B pointers to see if they point to the same instance, and i have been running into this issue while trying to implement it.

Comment: @android927 `dynamic_cast<B *>(ptr)`

Comment: @MattMcNabb That won't work because, in my case, ptr is a pointer that could point to any one of various classes that inherit from Base2. Would it work if i did `dynamic_cast<Base2 *>(ptr)` on both of the pointers i'm comparing?

Comment: @android927 `dynamic_cast<void*>` might possibly work---it gives you the address of the complete object. But you need to make sure that whatever is actually pointed to is polymorphic (*e.g.*, by making sure all classes you're doing this to have virtual destructors).

Comment: In order to compare two pointers reliably, they have to be pointing at the same data type, to ensure the alignments and such are the same.  Only then will two pointers to the same object line up correctly. You can't compare a `B*` to a `Base1*` or a `Base2*`, but you can compare a `B*` to a `B*`, a `Base1*` to a `Base1*`, a `Base2*` to a `Base2*`, etc. In this example, if you compare a `B*` to a `BaseX*`, the compiler might auto-downcast the `B*` to `BaseX*` before performing the comparison.

Comment: You can compare the identity of two `B` object via `Base2`. For any `B* b1, b2;` if `b1 == b2`, then `(Base2*)b1 == (Base2*)b2`. (unless Base2 were a virtual base)

Comment: @android927 I read your comment over again. Why not just `static_cast<Base2*>` and then compare, if you're sure that everything derives from `Base2`?

Comment: @Brian It doesn't work for some reason. In my code, i have the line `cout << static_cast<EventListenerClass*>(_listener) << " , " << static_cast<EventListenerClass*>(other._listener) << endl;` This outputs 2 different addresses, but i know for a fact that `_listener` and `other._listener` point to the same object. Dynamic casts and c-style casts don't work either, and dynamic casting to void* raises a  `__non_rtti_object` exception.

Comment: @android927 It's hard to say why that is. You should write a new question and post enough code for us to diagnose. My guess is that you have undefined behaviour. Anyway, `dynamic_cast<void*>` does work, but it should be a last resort. The operand must be of a polymorphic class type, and you must have RTTI turned on.

Answer (score 5):

`B` derives from `Base1` and `Base2`, so it consists of all the data that `Base1` and `Base2` contain, and all of the data that `B` adds on top of them.

`B::bar()` is passing a pointer to the `Base2` portion of itself to `A::for()`, not the `B` portion of itself.  `B::bar()` is printing the root address of the `B` portion, whereas `A::foo()` is printing the root address of the `Base2` portion instead.  You are passing around the same object, but they are different addresses within that object:

[image]

If `B` does not add any new data, its base address *might* be the same as the root address of its nearest ancestor (due to [empty base optimization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo)):

[image]

Don't rely on that.  A compiler might add padding between the classes, for instance:

[image: image2]

Always treat the various sections as independent (because they logically are).  Just because `B` derives from `Base2` does not guarantee that a `B*` pointer and a `Base2*` pointer, both pointing at the same object, will point at the same memory address.

If you have a `Base2*` pointer and need to access its `B` data, use `dynamic_cast` (or `static_cast` if you know for sure the object is a `B`) to ensure a proper `B*` pointer.  You can downcast from `B*` to `Base2*` without casting (which is why `B::bar()` is able to pass `this` - a `B*` - to `A::foo()` when it is expecting a `Base2*` as input).  Given a `B*` pointer, you can always access its `Base2` data directly.

Comment: But the addresses that are outputted are the same when i compile this code at codeingground. Try it yourself: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp11_online.php

Comment: @android927: that is not a guarantee in every compiler on every platform, or even within similarly-structured classes within the same program.